# Android: only in MOTO G5 Plus not uploading image

Tags: java, android, file-upload

I need help to upload image on server. Below code is working fine in all devices other than moto g5 plus.
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

```
    public void uploadFile() {
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, TIME_OUT_CONNECTION);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, TIME_OUT_SOCKET);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    httpClient.setParams(httpParameters);

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FirstName", userInfo.getFirst_name()));
        String paramsString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8");


        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(REGISTERATION_API + "?" + paramsString);

        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(new File("file path")), -1);
        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            status = line;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        status = e.getMessage();
    }


}
```

Comment: Please update your profile with the serial/IMEI/MEID number of your phone. Is it okay if we look into your apps? This will help us investigate. Make sure that your Motorola Privacy is enabled.

Comment: Already Motorola Privacy is enabled.

Comment: "not uploading image" Ok. But what happens instead? Should we guess?

Comment: You have a combined GET/POST request. Why?

Comment: `status = line;` That should be `status += line + "\n";`.

Comment: This issue is only in Moto G5 plus.

Comment: see my answer in your question to solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094922/android-only-in-moto-g5-plus-not-uploading-image/51095109#51095109

Answer (score 0):

> **Receiveing multiple errors when trying to use the camera on the Moto G5 Plus.  Where it asks to Please Restart Camera. After a few attempts
>   the camera does then work but is very frustrating.**
>
> **Have tried Settings > Apps > Camera > Storage > Clear Data but this does not always resolve the issue.**
>
> **If it does resolve the issue it is temporarily.**